# How to convert an array of key–value arrays to an array of objects with .reduce function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, reduce

Hello i am not a javascript programmer. What I want to achieve is that the output down with reduce. This script is going to be used in google scripts for that reason you have to use the `reduce` function.

Input

```
[
  [ 'foo', 3.672698 ],
  [ 'bar', 71.999747 ],
  [ 'baz', 107.400002 ],
]
```

Output

```
[
  { 
    name: 'foo', 
    money: 3.672698 
  },
  { 
    name: 'bar', 
    money: 71.999747 
  },
  { 
    name: 'baz', 
    money: 107.400002 
  },
]
```

Comment: Your Input is array of array as I see, but what are foo, bar and baz? just variables? of string type?

Comment: The same way you would normally use `Array#reduce`. Initial value of `[]` and be sure to return the accumulator within your callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```js
const input = [
  [ 'foo', 3.672698 ],
  [ 'bar', 71.999747 ],
  [ 'baz', 107.400002 ],
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({
    name: item[0],
    money: item[1]
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically asked for .reduce. But reduce is for reducing a set to a single value. The function you asked for is a service for .map. And Google Scripts will understand it also. Take a look at this example:

```js
var arr = [
  [ 'foo', 3.672698 ],
  [ 'bar', 71.999747 ],
  [ 'baz', 107.400002 ],
]

var res = arr.map(function(item){ 
     return {name: item[0], money: item[1]};
});
console.log(res);
```